# Преобразовать кавычки в елочки в столбце сформированной таблицы

Tags: регулярные-выражения, r

Есть проблема. Нужно в сформированной скриптом таблице, в одном из столбцов произвести замены по содержимому следующего типа:

**"текст"** заменить на **<<текст>>**

**стр. 12** заменить на **стр.12**

полная строка выглядит примерно так "п. 1, п. 2 Приложения 11АА (стр. 191)", соответсвенно нужно преобразовать в <<п.1, п.2 Приложения 11АА (стр.191)>>

так как таблица формируется по условию, то сказать размероность не могу.

Comment: для замены символов в строке в соответствии с регулярным выражением можете воспользоваться, например, [функцией `string_replace()` из пакета `stringr`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_replace.html).

Comment: это понятно. регулярка нужна. можно и так замену сделать `gsub("^\"", "<<", s)
gsub(" \"", " <<", s)
gsub("\"$", ">>", s)
gsub("\" ", ">> ", s)` но это мягко говоря не быстро для 100 строк. А если таблица генерируется на 10K?

Comment: «не быстро для 100 строк». возникает подозрение, что вы используете цикл.

Comment: А каким способом ещё можно обработать все ячейки в столбце? я использую цикл и `str_replace(s, '\"', '<<') %>% str_replace('\"', '>>')`

Comment: и `str_replace()` и `gsub()`, как и подавляющее число функций в *r* — векторизованы. т.е. им на вход можно передать вектор значений. собственно, вы так и делаете, только передаёте вектор единичной длины. а можно передавать вектор произвольной длины. для справки: столбец в таблице — это вектор. // обработка вектора происходит значительно быстрее, чем множественный вызов функции для каждого отдельного значения.

Comment: О! Спасибо больбшое! я новичёк в R, учусь в бою. Так что иногда использую далеко не оптимальные решения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В R есть возможность задать именной вектор с парами "регулярное выражение-шаблон замены" и передать его в `stringr::str_replace_all`:

```
text <- '"п. 1, п. 2 Приложения 11АА (стр. 191)"'
search_replace <- c('^"' = '<<', '"$' = '>>', '(стр\\.)\\s+(\\d)' = '\\1\\2')
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(text, search_replace)
## => [1] "<<п. 1, п. 2 Приложения 11АА (стр.191)>>"
```

Шаблон `^"` находит двойную кавычку в начале строки, `"$` находит такую кавычку в конце, а `(стр\.)\s+(\d)` находит `стр.` и помещает в подмаску №1 (`\1` в шаблоне замены), затем 1 и более пробельных символов, а затем любую цифру (которую помещает в подмаску №2 (`\2`)).

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/CmMOgx/2) и [пример работы кода на R](https://rextester.com/KHS4180).

Comment: Если вы работаете в Windows и у вас проблемы с поиском русского текста, замените русские буквы Юникод-последовательностями: ``search_replace <- c('^"' = '<<', '"$' = '>>', '(\\u0441\\u0442\\u0440\\.)\\s+(\\d)' = '\\1\\2')``

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: `text <- 'п. 1, п. 2 "Приложения 11АА" (стр. 191)'`

а если кавычки внутри строки?

Comment: @Paul `search_replace <- c('"([^"]*)"' = '<<\\1>>', '(стр\\.)\\s+(\\d)' = '\\1\\2')`, [демо](https://rextester.com/LXJC37028)